# Annotate a function type to accept either a React.MouseEvent parameter or to remain anonymous

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, mouseevent

I am refactoring some code that shows a dialog to the user based on whether they have selected the 'edit' or 'delete' option in a dropdown.

As I work to make the dialog component more generic, I am trying to make the `handleClose` event handler be either of type `() => void` or of type `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void`.

In order to achieve this I have annotated the `handleClose` event handler so that it accepts both; it currently looks like this `handleClose: () => void | ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void);`.

Great - but I'm still getting a mysterious error message that is confusing me.

Error message:

```
Type '(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void | ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void)'.ts(2322)
FolderEditView.tsx(13, 5): The expected type comes from property 'handleClose' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'
(JSX attribute) IProps.handleClose: () => void | ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void)
```

Where am I making a mistake in assigning two possible types?  And why does the error message seem to indicate that in `FolderEditView.tsx(13, 5)` I am annotating without the use of `React.MouseEvent...`?  The error message does not reflect the truth of what is written in my code, so it's hard to diagnose what's going on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this based on the error message (add the second generic type parameter as suggested):

```
(event?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void
```

`event?:` means the argument can be empty, you don't need to create a union of functions here

### [Live Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAERTo4DGMVA3ALABQHMAnmAQLIQ06ABI4AdgBMANuihwAvHAAU6AG7pxMAPwAuOACU6jAHSDhAUQ1aAPCIAq-ADIXZITTAA0ccxiseAPgBKRQC4NQhgSQ4OdAAPSFhSZHFGYAhxOAs4nHBZAEEwMGUQhA44OHoM1HgMgGFpYHoAa31fUQkZOUUVdBCFMIRCNk52CtoYZChM5XKKuBtJYDUAufmFgCNkGBgMuHrGloUEEtD98Qam5pLCAMuWuHcbAHotnYzVsfXN7d3Mg6ux1U-TCAJawNu92aj3QLzef0+6xeSxWcyCI0IQA)